# How to copy files using java resource adapters?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jca

I have a usecase which requires copying files to a mounted disk. Our continuous analyst said to use java resource adapter to do it. I am completely new to it and dont know where and how to start.

We use jboss eap 6.x application server with ejb 3.1.

A user uploads a file and I have to write code to validate it and then copy it to a mounted disk.

Can anyone please help me? I read many example online but I dont understand where can I get the rar from.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You can create your own JCA adapter, it is not that complex :-) Please see http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/ironjacamar/create-your-first-jca-connector-tutorial

Comment: Try this https://github.com/bartoszmajsak/javaee7-samples/blob/file-watcher-mdb/jca/mdb-filewatcher/README.md

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will read and get back if I any doubts.

Comment: I am not able to understand. :(

Comment: I read many posts and articles about JCA, resource adapters etc. But still not able to start writing my own adapter. Can anyone please shed some light. Basically I dont understand what is ManagedConnection, ManagedConnectionFactory. What should I write in the overwritten methods? In some examples I dont understand why instance of factory is sent to ManagedConnection. In this example http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/ironjacamar/create-your-first-jca-connector-tutorial?showall=&limitstart=